# mvc3 : Suggest controller structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am staring to get used to MVC and after a couple little learning projects, I am now ready to take a larger bite.

I am looking to work on a structure like this.
/admin/index
/admin/user/create:read:update:delete:list
/admin/news/create:read:update:delete:list

Given the last two, I am thinking that I should have controllers
Admin
AdminUser
AdminNews

... and that i should have views stored in these folders
/Views/Admin
/Views/Admin/User
/Views/Admin/News

Does the above sound ok?

Finally, how do i set up those routes to hit those controllers?

I tried something like this which did not work.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Admin/User", // Route name
    "/Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new {controller = "AdminUser", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am staring to get used to MVC and after a couple little learning projects, I am now ready to take a larger bite.

If you are starting to learn asp.net mvc , and trying to implement admin panel, i would suggest "Areas". Take a look at [Walkthrough: Organizing an ASP.NET MVC Application using Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much for the info and the link. I downloaded the sample solution and it is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the *areas* feature.

Seeing this:

- Admin
- AdminUser
- AdminNews

Leads me to think that you could add an *Admin* area and have separate controllers underneath that area. Then your Urls would be /Admin/User and /Admin/News etc.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that areas might be something you may want to look into as it is ideal for an admin type area and there are tonnes of examples for it in the web.

However if you were not going down that route, then to answer your question somewhat.

First.  The views would be in folders:

```
Views/Admin
Views/AdminUser
Views/AdminNew
```

Second.  The route need simply be the default route that is first setup in the project
i.e

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

where the action will be the methods exposed from Admin, AdminUser and AdminNew controllers.

To have the routing you mentioned you could do something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"AdminUser",
/Admin/User/{action},{id},
new {controller = "AdminUser", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

And likewise for news.  For Admin I believe the default route would catch that.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an area for the admin part.